# can't install mysql_xdevapi on ami linux2

Tags: protocol-buffers, php-extension, protoc, amazon-linux-2, mysql-x-devapi

I need mysql_xdevapi extension. trying through `sudo pecl install mysql_xdevapi`

error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check - **fixed**.
error: boost not found - **fixed**.
**error: protobuf not found** - this is the main problem((

```
...bla bla bla...
configure: checking for protobuf yes
checking google/protobuf/any.h usability... no
checking google/protobuf/any.h presence... no
checking for google/protobuf/any.h... no
checking for main in -lprotobuf... yes
checking for protoc... /usr/bin/protoc
configure: error: protobuf not found, please install it in system, consider use of --with-protobuf or setting MYSQL_XDEVAPI_PROTOBUF_ROOT
ERROR: `/var/tmp/mysql_xdevapi/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-boost --with-protobuf' failed
```

after `sudo yum install -y protobuf-compiler`
`protoc --version` libprotoc 2.5.0
But still doesn't work.
Okay, `Point out protobuf library install dir [autodetect] : /home/ec2-user/.lical/include` (I used [this](http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html) manual ) - steel doesn't work, because there are no files it needs.
[image]
no any.h
Any ideas?

ami linux2, php 7.3.2 libprotoc 2.5.0 -instaled and 'release' - unpacked in /home/ec2-user/.lical/include

Answer (score 0):

take protoboof from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/protobuf-cpp-3.14.0.zip) (unpack src to /usr/local as example)
and protoc from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.14.0/protoc-3.14.0-linux-x86_64.zip) (/bin/protoc to /usr/bin)
do not forget to specify the folder during installation (/usr/local/src)